# jQuery carousel issue: How do i stop the thumbnails from advancing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I'm working on modifying a carousel and current the thumbnails move out of frame. I'm looking for help to keep them stationary except for the blue thumbnail highlighter. I've created a jsFiddle which highlights the problem. http://jsfiddle.net/julianmiller/TWFad/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hacky version:** Put this in your CSS:

```
.buttonCover { left: 0 !important; }
```

**Less hacky version:** Remove the JS that is doing it. The block you'll want to modify is between lines 158 and 178 in the JS. Specifically:

```
E.stop(true, true).animate({
    left: -(o * D) + w
}, y)
```

Answer (score 3):

I've commented out a couple of chunks of Javascript - see the revised fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/GDPWC/

When it was moving the background it was using the "left" property. The blue box thing was moving using "margin-left". I just commented out anything setting "left".